# Do we have document management system in Kentico CMS? if yes how it can be integrated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico, document-management

I am evaluating Kentico CMS for some project and requirement is as following

"Do we have document management system in Kentico CMS? if yes how it can be integrated?"

Also needed to have granular permission on files uploaded in document management.

Please let me know on the same as I need to integrate it to my ASP.NET MVC project

Answer (score 0):

I would not call the way you can management documents in Kentico document management like SharePoint. It's more of a repository for you to manage completed documents, not full collaboration compare to SP.

Certainly, if you need only document repository with workflow for approval, versioning, viewing permission, and setup upload permission for different section, you can certainly use it just like how you would manage a page.

There is also the integration with SharePoint, which you can pull documents managed in SP into CMS for display purpose. https://docs.kentico.com/k11/integrating-3rd-party-systems/integrating-sharepoint